# How to put multiple links in one text

Tags: website-design, hyperlinks

I have a table which contains a list of ID's, each of the ID's will contain 2 links where the user can choose which link they want to open.

What's the best way to present this feature?

Here's what my table looks like.

[image]

The location represents the ID which only contains one link at the moment. 
I need to associate those locations with 2 links.

Comment: Is there a reason that each column has such a large right margin?

Comment: @Jasper Because user can hide/show columns in the table, when user show more and more columns the content will be more packed.

Comment: My understanding is that there is one canonical ID (not two), is that correct? What are the locations? Are they different types of detail views?

Comment: What is the difference between the first ID and the second? If you were talking about the two IDs with a user over the phone, how would you describe them?

Answer (score 4):

You can make each id number consistently be a link to one of the choices.

You can add a column adjacent to the id number that contains either a tiny icon or a very short string.  This column will be a link to the other choice.

You could even represent both links as icon columns, but it is not necessary to do so if you make the id be a link.

Answer (score 3):

## You can reveal a signifier on hover that users have to make a choice.

You have the link color, which is a signifier that *I can go to a destination.*

To keep the table from getting visually noisy, you can reveal as users hover anywhere in the cell, a dropdown signifier. This allows you to reveal a menu on click that provides a simple list.

This can also scale: if for some reason you have to add another item, you just put it in the menu.

By putting the items in the menu list, you can also have room to display long strings if need be (I don't know you're constraints).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of possible ways to think on the problem.

1. One click is preferable way to follow required link.
2. Both links have equal possibility to be clicked by user - we need to have two different clickable entities.
3. One of two links is more often clickable than another - make it clickable and then provide possibility to click another link after processing previous click.
4. Nothing above is suitable - we need to provide selection in two clicks.

Your choice depends on is it clear to user what to expect after click on your link.

Answer (score 0):

Adding two icons after the ID would make sense for the user. Set the color of the IDs to be in dark and the links in light blue so that the user understands that this is a link:

[image]